# MonthCalendar DateSelected Event not firing and I need code to execute when any single date is selected

Tags: c#, monthcalendar

I'm building an application in C# that will eventually open an existing notepad file on a date selected from the monthCalendar control or create a new blank notepad file.  I successfully built this application before in VB, but I'm having a problem in C#.

In VB, the code successfully lives under the:

Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected

subroutine and all works fine.

In C#, I cannot get any code under monthcalendar1_DateSelected to fire.  So I moved the code to live under monthCalendar1_DateChanged and it works as long as you don't select today's date -- which makes sense, the date hasn't changed.  However, I need my application to be able to work on today's date as well as any other date clicked on in the control.

Any thoughts on how to resolve? I need the code to execute no matter which date is selected - today or any other date.

I set MaxSelectionCount to 1 in the monthCalendar1 control properties.

```
   private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("DateChanged Fired!");
    }

    private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Show the start and end dates in the text box.
        MessageBox.Show("DateSelected Fired!");
    }
```

Comment: You are missing the register of the event "+=".  Search project for += to see where the DateChanged event is registered.  Then add register for DateSelected.

Comment: Bingo!  That was the problem.  I followed your instructions and it works as expected now.  Many thanks!